# Why doesn't the Lexer.cs recognize a lexical mode?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I've seen many examples of the implementation of lexical modes across this site as well as other places, like the Definitive Guide to ANTLR4. Before writing my own lexer grammar with lexical modes, I just wanted to try an example. So I copied the example from the [ANTLR Mega Tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/#lexical-modes):

```
lexer grammar MarkupLexer;
OPEN                : '[' -> pushMode(BBCODE) ;
TEXT                : ~('[')+ ;
// Parsing content inside tags
mode BBCODE;
CLOSE               : ']' -> popMode ;
SLASH               : '/' ;
EQUALS              : '=' ;
STRING              : '"' .*? '"' ;
ID                  : LETTERS+ ;
WS                  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
fragment LETTERS    : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

And imported it into a very simpler parser grammar:

```
grammar Example1;
import MarkupLexer;

any                 : .*;
```

All I wanted to see was if it would build successfully. However, I experienced the same error: `The name 'BBCODE' does not exist in the current context` with the error occurring in this auto-generated method:

```
private void OPEN_action(RuleContext _localctz, int actionIndex) {
    switch (actionIndex) {
    case 0: PushMode(BBCODE); break;
    }
}
```

I noticed the `modeNames` array in the auto-generated Lexer contains only `"DEFAULT_MODE"`.

What am I missing here? Why won't this build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using "import" when you should use "options { tokenVocab = MarkupLexer; }" instead. Your grammars should be:

MarkupParser.g4:

```
parser grammar MarkupParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = MarkupLexer ;
}

any                 : .*;
```

MarkupLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar MarkupLexer;
OPEN                : '[' -> pushMode(BBCODE) ;
TEXT                : ~('[')+ ;
// Parsing content inside tags
mode BBCODE;
CLOSE               : ']' -> popMode ;
SLASH               : '/' ;
EQUALS              : '=' ;
STRING              : '"' .*? '"' ;
ID                  : LETTERS+ ;
WS                  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
fragment LETTERS    : [a-zA-Z] ;
```